# AWS API Gateway routing by request body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Are there any solution(s) that the AWS API Gateway do the routing based on data of the HTTP request body without using any other AWS service(s) lambda etc etc? (My HTTP request body cotains only the environment ID)

I founded a solution where another AWS service help for processing of body data. If it possibe I'm looking for the solution where only AWS API Gateway is used in this case. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do routing based on the data in the request body only using API Gateway.

You can use the path and query string parameters to do routing.

See [Working with routes for HTTP APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html)

> API Gateway selects the route with the most-specific match, using the following priorities:
>
> Full match for a route and method
>
> Match for a route and method with a greedy path variable
>
> The default route